# D&d 5e pre-written campaign starting at level 3

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, campaign

I've been searching for a ready 5e campaign to run for a while now, but the issue is - most of them start at level 1. Since both me and my players find levels 1 and 2 boring in 5e, I've been looking for a campaign that starts at level 3, eventually higher if there isn't a 3+ one. Anyhow, since I've had no luck myself, I decided to ask here to see if anyone has something to recommend. Also, they don't need to be official WOTC books, as long as they fit 5e and start at a higher level.

Comment: Welcome to the stack, Averian. Take the [tour] when you have a moment. Unfortunately, recommendation questions are off topic here. Fortunately, we maintain a [curated list of forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) where your question may be better suited.

Comment: Reading through this again, we can revise it to be in topic by just asking “which official published adventures start at third level or higher?” This would be an objective, fact based question rather than an opinion based question. See [revision 3](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/revisions/197472/3) for my changes and roll back to that one if you want to take the question in that direction.

Comment: I also flubbed the title a bit in revision 3, but we can fix that if you decide to go with that form of the question.